# Error: you need to specify a file path to store the seed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, openssl, seed

I face an error in laravel4.

**ERROR :** 
`RuntimeException:`

You need to specify a file path to store the seed.

[image: I face this error in laravel4.]

When I remove the cookies of my site , it works fine.
I think that I enabled the `ssl_module` in my `wamp` .
**because :** 

First time when I wanted to install composer ,I got a warning message for not enabling `openssl` which I had already done in `WAMP`.

[image: warning message for not enabling <code>openssl</code>]

I enabled `;extension=php_openssl.dll` by removing the semicolon (;) from the beginning of the line in `php.ini` and `phpForApache.ini` and `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-development` .
After that it worked well and installed.

#### I don't know the problem ! help me,please .

---

I set virtual host in `WAMP`,use "`http://laravel.local/`" instead of this "`http://localhost/learnlaravel/public/`". I face that error with both of the `url`.

Comment: Run a `<?php phpinfo()` and see if it mentions openssl. I know it sounds stupid, but did you restart apache/wamp after modifying the config?

Comment: @ollieread yes,I restart wamp server.

Comment: Does `phpinfo` say that you have openssl installed?

Comment: @ollieread in Phar "Native OpenSSL support  enabled" and in mysqlnd "SSL  supported"

Comment: @ollieread If it dosen't install,how can I install openssl ?

Comment: @ollieread I removed the semicolon (;) from the beginning of "extension=php_openssl.dll" in "php.ini" and "phpForApache.ini" and "php.ini-production" and "php.ini-development" .

Comment: Create a file called `info.php` and add `<?php phpinfo()` to it, and then look for openssl.

Comment: @ollieread : I told you I saw `phpinfo()`,there are `Native OpenSSL support enabled` in `phar` part of it and `SSL supported` in  `mysqlnd` part of it.

Comment: So there isn't a section called `OpenSSL`?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :) ,
I understand that the **composer** see `wamp\bin\php\` for openssl,
because of it when I remove the semicolon (;) from  `;extension=php_openssl.dll in **php.ini**` in `wamp\bin\php\php.ini` ,the composer install (***but there isn't a section called OpenSSL in phpinfo()***).
But for enable openssl I should remove the semicolon (;) from `;extension=php_openssl.dll in **wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini**`,after that `openssl` enable and works properly.
now we can see a section called OpenSSL in phpinfo(): 
[image]

Comment: Its too bad that version of OpenSSL is vulnerable to a number of exploits.